# automatically make m variables for each row of (m x n) 2d ndarray

Tags: python, matrix, vectorization

say I have a m x n numpy matrix and I need to make m variables, one for each of the rows of the matrix. is there an automatic way to generate those variables and then call them all at once later on in my script?

e.g.
instead of saying

```
matrix = np.random.randn(5, 3)
a = matrix[0,:]
b = matrix[1,:]
c = matrix[2,:]
d = matrix[3,:]
e = matrix[4,:]

res = someOperation(a, b, c, d, e)
```

is there a way of automatically generating these variables for some arbitrary matrix of size m and then simultaneously calling them?
I have a matrix with a massive number rows and surely there must be a more graceful way.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to pass in the entire matrix and then inside if you want to apply the same equation to all the rows then you can iterate over the rows as follows

```
def someOperation(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        print(row)

matrix = np.random.randn(5, 3)
res = someOperation(matrix)
```

Otherwise if you want all the variables as letters the closest you could do would be to use a dictionary as follows this only allows for number of letters in the alphabet but you could always repeat letters if you wanted.

```
import string

matrix = np.random.randn(5, 3)
alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
matrixDictionary = {}

for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    matrixDictionary[alphabets[i]] = row

# example of how to access the key and row
for key in matrixDictionary.keys():
    print(str(key) + " | " + str(matrixDictionary[key]))
```